# Ошибка компиляции файла nloahmann/json

Tags: c++, json, компиляция, библиотеки

Через ковычки добавил "nloahmann/json.hpp", на сам include не жалуется, но при компиляции появляется около 300 ошибок, почему то сам файл JSON.HPP жалуется на то, что не может найти свои библиотеки

```
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: json.hpp]

[image: директорий проекта]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я помню, библиотека состоит из большого количества включаемых файлов, и они должны быть все скачаны с https://github.com/nlohmann/json и находиться в соответствующей папке.

Или можно взять папку `single_include` оттуда же — тут отдельные файлы соединены в один огромный...

Вы же, похоже, взяли из первого набора единственный файл.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: single include то, что надо, спасибо!!!!!!!!!